# AWS UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-dynamodb, amazon-cloudwatch

I just start to learn about AWS and I trying to upload the image into S3 Bucket manually. when the image is uploaded to bucket, it will trigger the function to register the person first and last name and store into DynamoDB. However, I unable store to the DynamoDB and it showing following error

```
UnboundLocalError: cannot access local variable 'index_employee_image' where it is not associated with a value
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 30, in lambda_handler
    raise e
  File "/var/task/lambda_function.py", line 17, in lambda_handler
    response = index_employee_image(bucket, key)
```

Code:

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition', region_name = 'ap-southeast-1')
dynamodbTableName = 'employee'
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='ap-southeast-1')
employeeTable = dynamodb.Table(dynamodbTableName)

# once upload the image will invoked the bucket name and file name is going to our event and object 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    # extract the key (1. bucket name 2. object image name)
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    try:
        response = index_employee_image(bucket, key)
        print(response)
        if response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200:
            faceId = response['FaceRecords'][0]['Face']['FaceId']
            # get the image name
            name = key.split('.')[0].split('_')
            firstName = name [0]
            lastName = name[1]
            register_employee(faceId, firstName, lastName)
            return response
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error processing employee image {} from bucket {} .'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e
    
    def index_employee_image(bucket, key):
        response = rekognition.index_faces(
            Image ={ 
            'S3Object':
            {
                'Bucket':bucket,
                'Name': key,
            }
         },
            CollectionId = "employees"
        )
        return response
    
    def register_employee(faceId, firstName, lastName):
        employeeTable.put_item(
            Item={
                'rekognitionId': faceId,
                'firstName': firstName,
                'lastName': lastName,
            }
        )
```

Comment: It seems you've indented your two functions too far. Put them at the same level as the request handler function

Comment: I get it already, thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Try this, with the functions indented to the root level.

```
import boto3

s3 = boto3.client('s3')
rekognition = boto3.client('rekognition', region_name = 'ap-southeast-1')
dynamodbTableName = 'employee'
dynamodb = boto3.resource('dynamodb', region_name='ap-southeast-1')
employeeTable = dynamodb.Table(dynamodbTableName)

# once upload the image will invoked the bucket name and file name is going to our event and object 
def lambda_handler(event, context):
    print(event)
    # extract the key (1. bucket name 2. object image name)
    bucket = event['Records'][0]['s3']['bucket']['name']
    key = event['Records'][0]['s3']['object']['key']

    try:
        response = index_employee_image(bucket, key)
        print(response)
        if response['ResponseMetadata']['HTTPStatusCode'] == 200:
            faceId = response['FaceRecords'][0]['Face']['FaceId']
            # get the image name
            name = key.split('.')[0].split('_')
            firstName = name [0]
            lastName = name[1]
            register_employee(faceId, firstName, lastName)
            return response
    except Exception as e:
        print(e)
        print('Error processing employee image {} from bucket {} .'.format(key, bucket))
        raise e
    
def index_employee_image(bucket, key):
        response = rekognition.index_faces(
            Image ={ 
            'S3Object':
            {
                'Bucket':bucket,
                'Name': key,
            }
         },
            CollectionId = "employees"
        )
        return response
    
def register_employee(faceId, firstName, lastName):
        employeeTable.put_item(
            Item={
                'rekognitionId': faceId,
                'firstName': firstName,
                'lastName': lastName,
            }
        )
```